# Why is this foreach statement not looping?

Tags: powershell, foreach

I've used this setup with a foreach statement multiple times and never had any issues. It points to a text file with multiple lines of input. However, this script only outputs the hard disk information for the first input line in the text file, and then stops. What's going on here?

```
# Create log file directory
New-Item -Path "C:\scripts\logs" -ItemType "directory" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Set script name
$ScriptName = "Hard_Disk_Count.ps1"

# Set script log file
$LogFile = "C:\scripts\logs\Hard_Disk_Count.log"

# Clear script log file
Clear-Content -Path "C:\scripts\logs\Hard_Disk_Count.log"

# Import VMware modules
Write-Host "Importing VMWare modules." -ForegroundColor Cyan
Import-Module VMware.VumAutomation
Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Storage
Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Common
Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.License

# Connect to a vCenter
$VIServer = "example"
Connect-VIServer -Server $VIServer

Try {
    # Prompt for confirmation that input file is updated
    $confirmation = Read-Host "Please confirm that the text file located at 'C:\scripts\input.txt' contains the correct information.`nEnter 'y' to proceed."
    if ( $confirmation -eq 'y' ) {
        $InputFile = Get-Content "C:\scripts\input.txt"
        foreach( $I in $InputFile ){        
            # Example write to log file
            Write-Host "Script $ScriptName started. Log file located at $LogFile." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            "$(Get-Date) - Script $ScriptName started." >> $LogFile

            $ClusterName = "$I"+"_Cluster"

            $VM =
            Get-Cluster $ClusterName |
            Get-VM |
            Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*190*" }

            $Disks = Get-HardDisk -VM $VM
            $DiskCount = $Disks.count
            "$VM, $DiskCount" >> $LogFile
        }

    }

}

Catch {
    # Error email message send
}
```

Comment: You're currently blinding yourself - output `$_` (or `throw`) from the `catch` block so you can see what is actually going on

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, this helped me figure it out after I put $_ in the catch block and was able to see the error. One of my inputs was causing the script to error out and stop because the *190* server did not exist for that cluster.